# JQUERY UI selectable() doesnt unselect with metaKey

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectable

So i'm having a table and in order to select and unselect this is my code :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){


$("table > tbody").bind("mousedown", function(e) {
  e.metaKey = true;
}).selectable();

 $( "table > tbody" ).selectable({

        filter: ":not(td)",
        selected: function( e, ui ) {
                if(1 < 28){
                $( ui.selected ).addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
                //var widget = $( this ).data( "uiSelectable" );
                // getAllTats( $(ui.selected) );
                }
                else{
                    alert('trop de tatouages');
                    $(ui.selecting).removeClass("ui-selecting");
                }
            },
        unselected: function( e, ui ) {
                alert('huh');
                $( ui.unselected ).removeClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
                //removeTat( $(ui.unselected) );
            },
     });



 });
```

It was working great until i tried at another place in my code a sortable(). Since then, my table refuse to unselect when i click on the selected elements.

I've looked what happenned with the CSS classes and it just refuses to remove ui-state-highlight

It worked again when i added the "selecting" event in my selectable, in that function i added an alert, but only if i cancel all possibility of showing me the alerts.

This is the HTML

```
<table class="tatooInk">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="//zms.be/42"></td>
            <td><b>Ancre marine </b></td>
            <td>Ancien marin ou engagé dans la marine. </td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="//zms.be/43"></td>
            <td><b>Jiao-long</b></td>
            <td>Mafieux d'origine asiatique. </td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="//zms.be/44"></td>
            <td><b>One Percent</b></td>
            <td> Biker criminel et membre d'un Motorcycle Club. </td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="//zms.be/45"></td>
            <td><b>Laugh before</b></td>
            <td> Mafieux cynique, sans-peur, et plein de sarcasme.</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="//zms.be/46"></td>
            <td><b>Sin Snake</b></td>
            <td> Drogué ou anciennement toxicomane. </td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="//zms.be/47"></td>
            <td><b>Croix nimbée</b></td>
            <td>Mafieux d'origine irlandaise. </td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="//zms.be/48"></td>
            <td><b>Corona trionfale</b></td>
            <td>Mafieux d'origine italienne. </td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="//zms.be/49"></td>
            <td><b>Christ Cross</b></td>
            <td> Ancien prêtre ou mafieux de confession chrétienne.</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="//zms.be/410"></td>
            <td><b>Barbed wire</b></td>
            <td> Mafieux ayant fait de la prison. </td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="//zms.be/411"></td>
            <td><b>Lénine</b></td>
            <td> Mafieux d'origine russe ou ex-URSS. </td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="//zms.be/412"></td>
            <td><b>Stout Beer</b></td>
            <td> Grand amateur de bière. </td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="//zms.be/413"></td>
            <td><b>United Kingdom MS1</b></td>
            <td> Mafieux d'origine anglaise, ou ayant servi dans l'armée anglaise. </td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><img src="//zms.be/414"></td>
            <td><b>USA Flags</b></td>
            <td> Mafieux d'origine nord-américaine, ou ayant servi dans les marines. </td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="//zms.be/415"></td>
            <td><b>Spider web</b></td>
            <td> Orphelin ou issue d'un milieu défavorisé. </td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table><!-- FIN TABLE -->
```

and at the end of my html

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="tatoo4.js"></script>
<script src="survol.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems the problem was my navigator. I restarted chrome and it was solved !